# How many Counter-Guardian does Alaya have?

Tags: fate-series

Other than FSN Archer, is there any revealed Counter-Guardian other than him?

Answer (score 1):

According to the [Wiki Category "Counter Guardians" on the Type-Moon Wikia](http://typemoon.wikia.com/wiki/Category:Counter_Guardians) there is 4 that are named but there can be more, as [Krazer mentions](https://anime.stackexchange.com/questions/47215/how-many-counter-guardian-does-alaya-have/50107#comment63317_47217) that 7 have appeared to retrain Primate Murder in certain Timelines but we do not know the names of these ones. 2 however were created parody/side works so they might not actually be proper Counter Guardians that Alaya can deploy

Anyway, the 4 Counter Guardians we know the names of are:

- [EMIYA (Emiya Shirou)](http://typemoon.wikia.com/wiki/Archer_(Fate/stay_night)): we know this one being **Archer** from *Fate/Stay Night*. a future version of Emiya Shirou
- [EMIYA (Emiya Kiritsugu)](http://typemoon.wikia.com/wiki/Assassin_(Fate/Grand_Order_-_EMIYA)): This one if from *Fate/Grand Order* as an **Assassin** Servant who is Kiritsugu, Shirou's adoptive father

  > Assassin's True Name is EMIYA, Kiritsugu Emiya. An assassin who was incarnated as an agent of the Counter Force. Originally, he was not a Heroic Spirit. Although he was an individual who murdered many people as an assassin, his existence has not been engraved in the Throne of Heroes. One of the “imitation Heroic Spirits” also referred to as Counter Guardians, and someone who would have never existed in the proper human history. Yet, this "if that might have been" possibility exists now only due to the threat that attempts to destroy human history itself from its very foundation... in the Grand Order case alone. His soul was called out from the circle of deterrence in response to this threat.
- [Okita Souji](http://typemoon.wikia.com/wiki/Devil_Saber): commonly know as **Devil Saber** who first appeared in the parody manga [Koha-Ace](http://typemoon.wikia.com/wiki/Koha-Ace). Devil Saber is isn't the same as [Sakura Saber](http://typemoon.wikia.com/wiki/Sakura_Saber) and is sorta like an Alter but not [listed as one](http://typemoon.wikia.com/wiki/Servant#Alter).

  > Devil Saber is a Counter Guardian formed through Sakura Saber's spiritual foundation taking in a Holy Grail filled with Seven Servants. Essentially an Okita Alter, her ascension grants her support from the Counter Force.
- [TOHSAKA](http://typemoon.wikia.com/wiki/TOHSAKA): first appearing as a **Master** (and not a Servant) in [*Capsule Servant*](http://typemoon.wikia.com/wiki/Capsule_Servant) which was a side game that was released with the PS Vita version of *Fate/Hollow Ataraxia*. as you can tell by the name she is Tohsaka Rin who became a Counter Guardian in a world where Shirou didn't

  > TOHSAKA is a "miraculous" Heroic Spirit born in a world line in which Shirou Emiya did not become the Heroic Spirit EMIYA.
  >
  > Because of her severe debt, she made a contract with the World to become a Heroic Spirit. Having decided that there were too many Grail Wars occurring across the different dimensions, and because she was a relatively new Heroic Spirit, the World tasked TOHSAKA with destroying the various Holy Grails, reducing her debt slightly for each one eliminated.

However because of the nature of *Koha-Ace* being self aware and the parody nature of *Capsule Servant* (ie. how [The World is shown](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yGFH5.jpg) to be [like Seele from *Neon Genesis Evangelion*](https://i.stack.imgur.com/V5KL7.jpg)) one could debate whether Alaya can actually deploy either one

Comment: It should be noted that the Kiritsugu that appears as a Counter Guardian is from a timeline where he didn't take part if the 4th Holy Grail War and therefore never adopted Shirou.

Comment: @IG_42 probably means he's from a world devoid of cute lil' Ilya

Comment: Possibly it's basically a world where Iri was Saber's master meaning that Kerry never met her either, in life at least. It's from a Fate/Grand Order event.

Comment: There are at least 7 Counter Guardians that restrain Primate Murder in certain timelines.

Comment: @кяαzєя are they named or just mentioned there's 7?

Comment: They are not named, from Comptiq 2005-09 issue -- "Fate Dojo Q&A" " It takes 7 Counter Guardians to control the Primate Murder and the Servants of the Grail War are based on these."

Answer (score 1):

Who knows. Counter Guardians are created when 'heroes' of the skill and power required to become a Heroic Spirit fail to attain the fame required to properly ascend to the Throne, and instead make a contract with Alaya in exchange for a 'miracle'.

By definition, then, a CG is 'someone we've never heard of' -- so who knows? Probably, just by statistics, there's more of them than there are Heroic Spirits - so hundreds, thousands, probably even more.

Talk about the Unknown Soldiers...